# How to include image as Markdown in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I include an image from the same destination folder as of the document as Markdown in Visual Studio Code?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
![Getting Started](./2/to/img.jpg)
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If the image is in the same directory as the Markdown file, you can use either:

```
![Getting Started](./img.jpg)
![Getting Started](img.jpg)
```

For a workspace layout like:

```
docs/
    images/
        img.jpg
    README.md
```

In `README.md`, this would be either:

```
![Getting Started](./images/img.jpg)
![Getting Started](images/img.jpg)
```

Comment: Do note that VS Code doesn't like spaces in the filename when including images.

Comment: Yes you have to percent encode urls. This is part of the markdown spec and not vscode specific

Comment: That might be, but I think it worked in both Pandoc and Gitlab.

Comment: I know this but others may not: replace each space with `%20`. For other characters, you'll need to look up "URL encoding" or "Percent-encoding": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: There must be no whitespace before the file command, if the file is on its' own line

Comment: This works although I did 2-3 mistakes here. Like having space in image name, putting image path inside quotes `![image]("img.png")` and also trying with global path of that image.

Answer (score 62):

Question is old, however, I found a very nice plugin within visual studio code
[Paste Image](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mushan.vscode-paste-image)

As the plugin suggests you can paste the image onto markdown file by pressing <kbd>ctrl(cmd)</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>V</kbd>.

Or

Open command palate pressing <kbd>ctrl(cmd)</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and select paste image. In the background the plugin creates a image file with date/time and puts reference on the markdown.

Comment: That's a fantastic plugin.

Comment: Does this work for WSL? I keep getting the error 'There is not an image on the clipboard'

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu & you get "xclip command not available error"
Try

```sudo apt-get update  
&& sudo apt-get -y install xclip```

Answer (score 11):

If you are here because the images would not render in vscode preview, here's my solution:

```html
<img src="./2/to/img.jpg" alt="Getting started" />
```

Markdown accepts HTML syntax, so this just works also.

Comment: This does not appear to work in VS code, in v1.65.1

Comment: I'm on 1.68.0, and it works. It might be because I have Markdown extensions installed, although it still worked after I disabled them and restarted VSCode.

Comment: Re-opening my folder/workspace in VS Code might have solved my issue. I thought it has something to do with my workspace root but nope. Wouldn't reproduce.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this Process you can just **drag the image** from the file and to include in the Readme.md just click `Shift + release` It Will be generated Automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the pic is from the internet
I think this code will work `![Getting Started](link to access the image)`

Answer (score 0):

If the image isn't rendering, in VSC it needs an extra line after the line where the image is instantiated, in other words it can't be an end of file. I do not see this requirement in other markdown editors.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting images seems to be currently in experimental phase on VSCode.
According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164843#issuecomment-1294460344), you can set the following configuration options on your personal settings to enable it.

```json
"markdown.experimental.editor.pasteLinks.enabled": true,
"editor.experimental.pasteActions.enabled": true
```

My test run of it worked perfectly pasting a screen capture, but it seems there's currently no setings as on where the file will be saved or its name. It defaults to saving on the current folder with "image.png" name.